# Trying to print out the key of dictionary after converting it from a csv using dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas
import random
import datetime
PLACEHOLDER = "[NAME]"

data = pandas.read_csv("birthdays.csv")
new_dict = {row.month: row.name for (index, row) in data.iterrows()}
print(new_dict["month"])
```

it is throwing an error when I try to print out `new_dict["month"]`

```
ERROR:
KeyError: 'month'
```

What the CSV file contains:

name,email,year,month,day

john,johndoe123@gmail.com,1995,1,6

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use the `dot` notation just replace `iterrows` by `itertuples`:

```
new_dict = {row.month: row.name for row in data.itertuples()}
```